# Running a sudo command line in the start of Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard, stunnel

I am using a Mac OS X - Snow Leopard. And to connect in our CVS we need to start the stunnel.

All time I have to go to "Terminal" and write

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/stunnel
=> than write the password
```

In have no idea, so my question is: How I automatic write this command every time that the Mac OS X start? Or in this case, start a program in super-user mode?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a startup item (`/Library/StartupItems/stunnel/stunnel`; see the mysql startup item for guidance on how to set it up) or add a line in `/etc/rc.common`

Comment: The line in rc.common is better :P Thanks.. So simple and I didn't find in on google.

Comment: I dont think there are enough osx power users out there ...

Comment: Note that the shell script must provide specific shell functions based on the StartupItems format, or it won't work see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/StartupItems.html - however, this is deprecated and launchd should be used instead - see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ

Comment: Editing /etc/rc.common is easy, but not a great idea - some StartupItem jobs will call this file for initialisation, so the script may get run multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Put `/opt/local/bin/stunnel` in `/etc/rc.common`.

Comment: There is no rc.local, but there is the rc.common. Well, local is for one Mac count and common is for all? So there is no problem put in other file, right?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Yeah, that should be fine.

Comment: @Rodrigo I love how the incorrect google-response is the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Foo Bah I don't understand your comment :P

Comment: @Rodrigo oh no I was just joking about the fact that the correct answer is to put the command in `/etc/rc.common`, yet it seems you accepted an answer which does not work (using /etc/rc.local).  If you just google, the /etc/rc.local recommendation shows up first

Answer (score 3):

It'd be better if you use [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html).